# Execute a script and while executing other one should be uploading it's output

Tags: bash, multitasking

I have 2 scripts, one that executes a task (that generates a lot of output) and the other one that uploads the output to the internet. I want to start executing the first one, and every 5 seconds the uploading script should upload the output. And when the one that's executing the task finishes, the uploading script also finishes

Comment: You want to start both, but have them finish in some predetermined order? If the second uploads results from the first, why not just do them sequentially?

Comment: Because the first one can stay an hour executing, with a really big output. And the second one should be constantly uploading the output. So while the first one is executing, the second one is also executing. The second one is an infinite while, that should be stopped when first script finishes

Comment: You'd better change your second script to detect the end of the input from the first and finish gracefully by himself IMO

Comment: Can I make a while [ command ] do upload? So that the upload is called everytime until command finishes

Answer (score 0):

There can be many available options to achieve what you said.

One available options is to perform the

```
pkill -f script2.sh
```

After the first one is finished.

A better way could be create a third master script that handle the start and the stop of the script1 and script2

Comment: Please specify more about that third master script

Answer (score 0):

You should have the upload script control the task script:

```
execute_task.sh &
task_pid=$!

# do the preliminary stuff for the upload script

# now, wait until the task is done:
wait "$task_pid"

# then carry on with the upload commands...
```

Comment: I want to constantly upload, not when it has finished. Because the first script will be saving it's output to a file, and the second one should be constantly uploading it. So that it's "live"

Answer (score -2):

Try somethink below:

```
while true
do
    if [[ `pgrep first.sh | grep -c` == 0 ]];then
        kill -9 `pgrep firsh.sh`
        kill -9 `pgrep second.sh`
        echo "Processes killed"
        break
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Infinite loops with no pauses are not recommended.

Comment: This has actually been discussed and answered before. I down voted your answer because it's wrong, `pgrep whatever|grep -c` will always produce an error message.

Comment: It's also either a really poor approach or a big misunderstanding of the OP's question. Either way it makes for a bad answer.